# require on client side (node module gives a dep error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, browserify, i18next

I'm trying to use browserify to bundle my js into a file and be able to use require on the client side.

But everytime I run browserify or watch on my app.js I get an error from i18next module.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jquery' from '/home/js/testapp/node_modules/i18next/lib/dep'
```

I've checked i18next and it doesn't need jquery (if it's not available) (no errors are given running the server).

I've tried installing jquery, that problem disappears but other emerges:

```
/home/js/testapp/node_modules/i18next/lib/dep/i18next.js:1245
        $.fn.i18n = function (options) {
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'i18n' of undefined
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's needed to disable jQuery.

Added a config to i18n init (in docs: http://i18next.com/pages/doc_jquery.html)

`setJqueryExt: false`

Now I have this config and no errors

```
app.use(i18n.handle);

i18n.init({
    cookieName: 'lang',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: 'true',
    setJqueryExt: false
});
```